# Accepted answer comes second in answers list

Tags: support, accepted-answer

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792833/unable-to-open-debugger-port-in-intellij) is a question with an accepted answer. However, another answer is shown *above* the accepted answer. How is this possible?

See also this screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Because it's a self-answer, it doesn't get the drag-to-top.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is a self-answer.

You can see this from the light blue background of the user's card.

Self-answers that are accepted are not placed at the top. They are the exception to the rule.

Reference: [this SO blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/), point 2.